# How to split an integer into String and Convert it automatically by seconds/minutes/hours

Tags: java, string, int, converters

I have set and displayed a timer on GUI.

I want the program to Save the time and load it. I did it successfully but,
I Want whenever the program start, to load the previou time.

`ms` is Milliseconds that every so if it passes 1000 it converts it to 1 seconds and get's the value of 0 again. I Have created a second (millisecondTimer) as (score) to display and not change it to 0. The score doesn't reset's itself until the timer stops.

I Want to grab the score and extract in with an order to get the values of:

**Minutes**/**Seconds**/**Milliseconds**.

I Have tried to extract it or divide it by different numbers but it's too difficult to me :/

Simply, I want to automatically detect the length of a score and get the Minutes, seconds and milliseconds on a String and display it after on `JLabel`.

I could create other integers as `milliBackup`, `secondsBackup`, `minuteBackup`.
and pass them separately to miliseconds/seconds/minutes. But I want to do it in this way if it is able.

```
public void beginTimer() {

            score++;
            ms++;

            if(ms==1000) {

                ms = 0;
                s++;

                if(s>59) {

                    s = 0;
                    m++;

                    if(m>59) {

                        timer.cancel();

                    }
                }

            }

            lblTimer.setText(displayTimer());

        }
```

and DisplayTimer has:

```
public String displayTimer() {
            return String.format("%02d:%02d:%03d", m, s, ms);
        }
```

Comment: It is better to use Java `DateTime API`. Take a look at http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/jf14-date-time-2125367.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How to calculate minutes (m), seconds (s), and milliseconds (ms) from `score`:

```
ms = score; 
s = ms / 1000; // integer div
ms = ms % 1000; // remainder
m = s / 60; // integer div
s = s % 60; // remainder
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't say how you're updating the method. If you're calling `Thread.sleep`, extra care should be used. There are better methods. But using your code:

```
// bad use of static but once you'll get it working, change it
static long s = 1;
static long m = 1;
static long ms = 1;

// the method is not beginTimer but updateTimer and goes inside a
// loop or something which calls it agan and again
public void updateTimer() {

        if(ms==1000L) {                  
            ms = 0;
            s++;  

            if(s==60L) {                      
                s = 0;
                m++; 

                if(m==60L) {                          
                    timer.cancel();                         
                }
            }                   
        }               
        lblTimer.setText(displayTimer());               
    }
```

Comment: I use timer from util package. here is the cod: timer = new Timer();
     
     TimerTask timerTask = new TimerTask() {

      @Override
      public void run() {
       
       beginTimer();
       
      }
      
     };
     
     timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(timerTask, 1, 1);

Comment: Nice. Bear in mind that `TimerTask` does not guarantees real time execution. E.g. won't ensure it will update the counters on the exact milliseconds. But it certainly will update the correct **number of times** on the long run.

Comment: hmm.. What's the best way to run the most accurate timer?

Comment: I think that to redraw a circular timer on the screen, you should avoid milliseconds and schedule directly to seconds. If the operating system isn't overloaded by other processes, that should be enough.